# @font-face is not working on any browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Can someone please assist me, I'm struggling to make @font-face work.
I have tried just about everything, I know I'm probably missing something silly.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: "Asbah";
  src: url('http://www.dafont.com/asbah.font.ttf') format ('truetype'),
  url('http://www.dafont.com/asbah.font.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('http://www.dafont.com/asbah.font.woff') format('woff'),
  p {
    font-family: 'Asbah';
    font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<p>
  Hallo this is font Asbah...which is noooot workingggg
<p>
```

Comment: Download these font to local system & try. when we hit the font in give url browser return 404 error.

Comment: these URL's return a 404, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Different browser use different font format. If you don't have some format at this website you car generate all: https://transfonter.org/

Take a look at this for technical insight: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure font URL is correct. Or serve it from CDN or Local

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `mime types` properly?
I think you can have a look here in this link:
http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face` only work on fonts which are hosted on your server.

Otherwise you need to use `@import`.

Like you want to use google fonts then -

`@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);`